# How to use mutual authentication without CA in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, mutual-authentication, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I want to use some certificateless mutual authentication methods in hyperledger fabric. but it seems fabric needs a CA. is there any solution for this? am i wrong or fabric really needs CA all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CA provides certificates to fabric for MSP user which is used to perform transactions in network and it also issues certificates for other user as well. without MSP you cannot perform any transaction in fabric so CA is pretty much important although if you follow read the docs you can go through build your first network which uses binaries to generate certificates for MSP but that's only for test/dev environment you cannot run it for production env.